# Column Visibility is not restored from a saved state via stateLoadCallback

Tags: datatables

I have added the Column Visibility button to choose to show or hide certain columns. I'm saving the state in a database, I call the stateSaveCallback function via a click on a button.

I cant find documentation about retrieving data this way, so I just link to the page and pass variables to get the data back from the database, and then load that using stateLoadCallback.

Now all this works fine, EXCEPT the column visibility is not restored. It is in the JSON data being returned though.

Here is my full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "date-uk-pre": function (a){
            return parseInt(moment(a, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("X"), 10);
        },
        "date-uk-asc": function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        },
        "date-uk-desc": function (a, b) {
            return b - a;
        }
    });



    var edit_date_col_num = $('th:contains("Edit Date")').index();
    var entry_date_col_num = $('th:contains("Entry Date")').index();

    var table = $('.mainTable').DataTable( {

        pageLength: 50,
        colReorder: true,
        stateSave: true,

        columnDefs: [
            { "type": "date-uk", targets: [ edit_date_col_num, entry_date_col_num ] }
        ],

        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print',
            {
                extend: 'colvis',
                collectionLayout: 'fixed four-column',
                postfixButtons: [ 'colvisRestore' ]
            }
        ],



        <?php
        $id = $this->input->get('id');
        $action = $this->input->get('action');
        if(isset($action) && $action == 'load' && isset($id) && $id != '') :
        ?>
        "stateLoadCallback": function (settings) {
            var o;

            // Send an Ajax request to the server to get the data. Note that
            // this is a synchronous request since the data is expected back from the
            // function
            $.ajax( {
                "url": EE.BASE + "&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=ion&method=state_save&action=load&id=<?php echo $id;?>",
                "async": false,
                "dataType": "json",
                "success": function (response) {
                    response = JSON.parse(response);
                    o = response;
                }
            });

            return o;
        },
        <?php
        endif;
        ?>

        initComplete: function (settings) {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );

            // Need to re-apply the selection to the select dropdowns
            var cols = settings.aoPreSearchCols;
            for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++)
            {
                var value = cols[i].sSearch;
                if (value.length > 0)
                {
                    value = value.replace("^", "").replace("$","");
                    console.log(value);
                    $("tfoot select").eq(i).val(value);
                }
            }

        },

    } );


    // Save a datatables state by clicking the save button
    $( ".save_state" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        table.destroy();
        $('.mainTable').DataTable( {

            colReorder: true,
            stateSave: true,

            "stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {

                var save_name = $('.save_name').val();

                // Send an Ajax request to the server with the state object
                $.ajax( {
                    "url": EE.BASE + "&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=ion&method=state_save&action=save&save_name="+save_name,
                    "data": data,
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "success": function (response)
                    {
                        //console.log(response);
                    }
                } );

            },


        });


        //table.state.save();
        window.location.replace(EE.BASE + "&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=ion&method=applications");
    });


    $( ".clear_state" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        table.state.clear();
        window.location.replace(EE.BASE + "&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=ion&method=applications");
    });


} );
```

Here is the saved JSON with several visible false in the beginning (which are visible once loaded):

```
{"time":"1449338856556","start":"0","length":"50","order":[["0","asc"]],"search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"},"columns":[{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"false","regex":"true","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"false","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}},{"visible":"true","search":{"search":"","smart":"true","regex":"false","caseInsensitive":"true"}}],"ColReorder":["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70"]}
```

Thanks

Comment: were you able to find solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case datatables rejects old data according to "stateDuration" and "time" properties..

Solution: ignore state duration

```
   "stateSave": true,
   "stateDuration": -1,
```

Above case:
"visible":**"false"** may should be "visible":**false**

Answer (score 0):

After a while of debugging this myself here's what worked for me..

This issue is that all the values in your JSON are strings and they need to be of correct datatypes for the datatables plugin.

Within the "stateSaveCallback" ajax request to save your state I did the following to the json string and then it saved all the values properly which then loaded the state as it should.

```
"stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {

    var save_name = $('.save_name').val();

    // Send an Ajax request to the server with the state object
    $.ajax( {
        "url": EE.BASE + "&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=ion&method=state_save&action=save&save_name="+save_name,
        //"data": data,
        "data": JSON.stringify(data), // change to this..
        "dataType": "json",
        "type": "POST",
        "success": function (response)
        {
            //console.log(response);
        }
    } );

},
```